# Mpandroidchart Two color in GradientDrawable

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Do you think I can change the color if Y value is less than zero?

Like

[image: this]

My line looks like

[image: this]

My code:

```
 set1.setDrawFilled(true);

 GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
 gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F7CA86"));

 set1.setFillDrawable(gradientDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use,

```
 Paint paint = mChart.getRenderer().getPaintRender();
                paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 40, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

Comment: No, this doing something else.